# Mkdocs showing source code from site-packages instead of project directory

Tags: mkdocs, mkdocstrings

I'm new to documentation tools and I'm trying to produce documentation to my Python project. I'm facing a weird issue where `mkdocs` is looking at the python files in site-packages instead of project directory. [image]. How do I make it point to files in the project directory instead?

Comment: Info is a bit light, but you might need to use the `paths` option to specify where to look for your sources. By default it uses `PYTHONPATH` (or `sys.path`), and so will naturally find your package sources in the venv. See https://mkdocstrings.github.io/python/usage/#finding-modules.